# How do I map volume to WSO2 API Manager Container?

Tags: docker, wso2-api-manager

I am using WSO2 API Manager Docker version for my API Gateway. I want to persist the files on the disk so that configurations are not lost during restarts. However, When I map the volume using docker "-v" command, WSO2 cannot find any files. Here is my complete docker command.

```
docker run --rm -d \
--name api-gateway \
--expose 9443 \
--expose 8280 \
-v /home/ubuntu/wso2am-2.6.0:/home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.6.0 \
wso2/wso2am:2.6.0
```

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have mounted to the root directory of `API` `Manager` installation. This should mount to the following location.

```
/home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.6.0/repository/deployment/server
```

This is where we store `Synapse` artifacts for the gateway.

Comment: I get the below error when i mount the synapse-config path


`[2020-02-18 06:55:14,472] FATAL - ServiceBusInitializer Couldn't initialize the ESB...
org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: The synapse.xml location ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default doesn't exist`

Comment: Can u try with the following path? /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.6.0/repository/deployment/server

Comment: No even this path doesn't work


I tried a workaround 
`##1. Run wso2 docker container without any volume mapping
##2. Copied /home/wso2carbon/wso2am-2.6.0/ directory to disk using docker cp command
##3. Stopped the container and started again by mounting this copied folders`

This works like charm but i cant use this process everytime